# Kinetic Text doesn't appear

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to add Kinetic Text to my page and it's not working. It must be something little I'm doing that isn't right.

This is my code:

```js
  var text = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    text: 'text',
    fontSize: 44,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    textFill: 'black'
  });
  layer.add(text);
```

Here is a Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/T8m64/90/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, kineticjs changed 'textFill' to just 'fill'. Working: http://jsfiddle.net/T8m64/91/

```
var text = new Kinetic.Text({
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
  text: 'text',
  fontSize: 44,
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  fill: 'black'
});
```

This is because they removed the background rectangle so only text appears. 
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-tutorial/

Comment: also, font size is in pixels now.